# Project spring boot does not recognize dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have initialized a spring boot starter project with [spring boot initializer](https://start.spring.io/). My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<groupId>com.stuff</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>my-project</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.12.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run Maven test I get :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
```

but In the dependecies, there is the class in question! (adding Junit 4.12 as dependency in pom won't change anything)

When I run the application as spring boot application I get an other NoClassFounder Error ! `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory`
Even if this dependecy also exists in Maven dependecies?

I m using Eclipse Kepler, Java 7, Maven 3.2

Comment: Do you get the error when you run `mvn clean install` from command line or is only in Eclipse?

Comment: what is the scope of slf4j library? I see that test spring-boot-starter-test library has "test" scope. If somehow class that comes from that test-scoped library is required during application runtime it will obviously throw such error. Perhaps you could push your project to github so we can help a little bit more.

Comment: mvn clean install throws same error @KarolDowbecki